# Leaflet + local .osm file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I've been using leaflet.js to render maps like it is shown in [leaflet getting started page](http://leafletjs.com/):

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { ...
```

I've download a .osm file (map.osm) from [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and I'm triying to figure our how can I use this file from leaflet like:

```
L.tileLayer('file:///./map.osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { ...
```

In other cases I've used [Mobile atlas creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) to download map layer and use them in leaflet. It downloads selected maps in a directory structure like zoom - x - y .png files (like: file_system\local_maps_dir\13\4049\2999.png where 13 is zoom latitude 4049 and longitude 2999).

But now I need to load or use these .osm files with leaflet.

Is there any way to do this? Do I need to convert this .osm file?

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Leaflet requires raster [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) whereas a .osm (or .pbf) file contains raw vector data. In order to produce raster tiles out of vector data you have to [render](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Renderers) it. This can't be done by Leaflet directly but requires external tools instead.

Rendering tiles locally can be done for example by using [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) or [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill). You might need another step for extracting individual tiles from the produced [MBTiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MBTiles).

Comment: Hi. It is not that I don't want to use .osm file, I've been provided by one .osm file and I didn't know how to use it with leaflet (it is not possible). So the answer is that I need to render a .osm file using a server? what would be the simplest way to do this? Thanks you a lot for your answer!

Comment: I've extended my answer a little. But I've never done this procedure myself.